# How to get the current attribute value in Xml and using the current attribute value, retrieve the next node value?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <questions>
      <question num="1">Employees should be involved in setting their goals.</question>
      <question num="2">Most people resists change.</question>
      <question num="3">Manager should guide rather control.</question>
      <question num="4">Average person is easily decieved.</question>
    </questions>
```

How can I set a current attribute value to a variable i, using this current attribute i when a method next() is called, it should retrieve next node value (for example if current attribute value is 1 when the next() is called it should retrieve 2nd node value and when again next() is called it should retrieve 3rd attribute value) using System.Xml?

I have tried to retrieve the first node value using Xpath, but I have no idea how to set the current attribute value to a variable and then using the variable moving to the next node value. The following is the code I have tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
    interface IQuestion
    {
        void Question1();
        void Next();

    }
    class Question : IQuestion
    {
         string BuildXpathQuery(int c)
        {

            string part1 = @"questions/question[@num='";
            string part2 = @"']";
            string MyQuery = part1 + c + part2;
            return MyQuery;

        }
        public void Question1()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Murari\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication14\\ConsoleApplication14\\XMLFile1.xml");


            XmlNode xnList = doc.SelectSingleNode(BuildXpathQuery(1));
            if (xnList != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(xnList.InnerXml);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public void Next()
        {

        }    
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IQuestion ques = new Question();
            ques.Question1();
            ques.Next();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simple need to create a a List<> object.  Using XML Linq is best way

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var xnList = doc.Descendants("question").Select(x => new
            {
                num = (int)x.Attribute("num"),
                text = x.Value
            }).ToList();

            foreach (var question in xnList)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```